# What is the difference between ‘used’ and ‘visited’ an app on google Activity page?

Tags: google-play-store

I’ve seen these two entries whilst looking at my google Activity page and just wanted to know the difference? I assume ‘used’ means I actually opened the app and used it so what would ‘visited’ an app mean?

Answer (score 3):

"Used" means you opened and used the app, which implies you had it installed at the time.

"Visited" means you went to the app's page on the Play Store, or, presumably, another app store. This can be of interest to parents who want to keep track of their children's apps and usage, as described [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/234743/does-visited-name-of-app-shown-on-googles-my-activity-mean-that-the-app-has).